# ASP.NET Core: A compatible SDK version for global.json version 2.1.400 was not found

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild

I've got an ASP.NET Core project in my solution, targeting .NET Core 2.1. I've added a global.json file at the solution level:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.400"
  }
}
```

On the Team City agent, I've installed MSBuild Tools 2017 (15.8.1), including .NET Core Build Tools.

From the command line I can see SDK 2.1.400 is installed on the agent:

```
>dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

However, building the solution fails on Team City with the following error:

```
dashboard.csproj : error : Unable to locate the .NET Core SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.
Dashboard.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.
A compatible SDK version for global.json version: [2.1.400] from [X:\agent-1\sandbox1\global.json] was not found
```

Any idea why it wouldn't find SDK 2.1.400 when building with MSBuild given it's present in the SDK list?

Comment: Is your Tean City agent run with a specific user or a system account ?

Comment: Yes, however, I ran `dotnet --list-sdks` under that account and the response lists `2.1.400`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally worked out that `dotnet` was not recognised as a command when running on Team City (despite `dotnet` being recognised as a command from the prompt, under the same Windows account).

The solution for me was to update the `PATH` environment variable using Team City parameters:

```
Name: env.PATH
Kind: Environment Variable
Value: C:\Program Files\dotnet;%env.PATH%
```

It now works as expected.

Comment: This also works for Jenkins under global configuration of environment variables. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the PATH environment variable points to the location where the SDK is installed (C:\Program Files\dotnet\ for 64-bit/x64 or C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\ for 32-bit/x86). The SDK installer normally sets the PATH. Always install the same bitness SDKs and runtimes on the same machine.

Comment: Verify the location  " C:\Program Files\dotnet\" that has all the SDKs you want  then ADD this to PATH in environment variable  C:\Program Files\dotnet\